# Trying to kill processes in bash - code embedded in [...] not run?

Tags: bash

here is what I want to do

```
while ["ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}'" != ""] ; do
  kill ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}'
done
```

meaning if the grep returns nothing, don't try a kill.
The thing is I've always been lost with the expression evaluation in bash, sometime I use `" "` around something, sometime it's `eval`, sometime it's `''`.

Could someone explain to me how to write the condition in my loop and explain the difference between the above? I'm used to find the working one with many tries and it feels like a huge loss of time.

Comment: Running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ would be a place to start.

Comment: thx a lot! I used killall mono is way better.

what do you mean by a command substitution? I'm not sure I understand this term.

Comment: "Command substitution" is when you wrap a command in `$(...)`, which expands to that command's output (after string-splitting and glob expansion if unquoted) when run.

Comment: By the way -- as a rule, don't ever use `eval`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for a discussion of how it creates security risks; moreover, it's rarely if ever necessary (and safe use requires a significant level of expertise).

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is a good place to start if you're looking for an introductory guide that's edited for accuracy and best practices.

Comment: thx a lot for all this help!! added shellcheck to my favorite ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Best choice: Do something else.

Utilities already exist for this purpose. Example:

- `killall mono`
- `pkill mono`

...or, even better, something targeted to the specific executable you want to terminate:

- `fuser -k /path/to/something.exe`

  ...which would kill only programs with a file handle on that specific executable, rather than *all* applications running with `mono` on the machine.

---

### ...but, to explain the bugs:

There are two things wrong here: Missing command substitutions, and missing whitespace.

- Missing whitespace:

  ```
  ["ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}'" != ""]
  ```

  ...is literally trying to run a command with a name starting with `[ps`, as in, looking in the PATH for...

  ```
  /bin/[ps\ a
  /usr/bin/[ps\ a
  ```

  ...etc. `[` is a **command**, and needs a space after its name like any other command. Thus:

  ```
  [ "ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}'" != "" ]
  ```

  ...fixes this problem (but leaves another one).
- Missing command substitutions:

  ```
  [ "ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}'" != "" ]
  ```

  ...is comparing a string that starts with `"ps a"` to to `""`; it **does not** compare the output of running a *command* that starts with `ps a`. To do that, you'd instead run:

  ```
  [ "$(ps a | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $1}')" != "" ]
  ```

  The content of `$(...)` is replaced with the output of the command within; thus, running your pipeline and comparing its output to an empty string.